# Obj-C UITable not populating with MutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an array that loads when the app starts and it gets the correct data and fills the array but once I go to the tableviewcontroller it says the array is null.

This is where I get the data

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *tableDicsArrayTickets;
    NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
    NSMutableString *textInProgress;
    NSError *errorPointer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableDicsArrayTickets;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *photo_URL;
+(NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+(NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+(AppDelegate *) getInstance;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.tableDicsArrayTickets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MYURLexample.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *deviceCode = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"parameter=%@", deviceCode];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
        if(error == nil)
        {
            NSString *text =[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

            NSDictionary *dics = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[AppDelegate dictionaryForXMLString:text error:nil]];

            NSLog(@"dics is %@", dics);
            [self.tableDicsArrayTickets addObject:[[dics valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
            NSLog(@"Array2 is %@", self.tableDicsArrayTickets);

        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface HistoryViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *mainDelegate;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *mainDelegate;
```

ViewController.m

```
#pragma
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [mainDelegate.tableDicsArrayTickets count];
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableArray *array = mainDelegate.tableDicsArrayTickets;
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PhotoTableViewCell *cell = (PhotoTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[PhotoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    }
    NSLog(@"Array is %@", [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"]);
    cell.ticketNumber.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
}
```

Im not having a problem getting the data for the array its just once I finally go to the view controller with the table on it the array becomes null.

Comment: You have to show the code where you are getting the data, and how you are instantiating `mainDelegate`.

Comment: @DonMag Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing a number of things wrong...

First:

```
// AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    // this should NOT be here
    NSMutableArray *tableDicsArrayTickets;

    NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
    NSMutableString *textInProgress;
    NSError *errorPointer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableDicsArrayTickets;
// ...
```

That should give you a compile warning:

```
autosynthesized property 'tableDicsArrayTickets' will use synthesized instance
variable '_tableDicsArrayTickets', not existing instance variable 'tableDicsArrayTickets'
```

Same with:

```
//HistoryViewController.h

@interface HistoryViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    // this should NOT be here
    AppDelegate *mainDelegate;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *mainDelegate;
```

Which should give you:

```
autosynthesized property 'mainDelegate' will use synthesized instance 
variable '_mainDelegate', not existing instance variable 'mainDelegate'
```

Then, you're not showing where you have this in `HistoryViewController.m` (should probably be in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
_mainDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Ok I edited it using what you showed me and I believe I got further the only thing stopping it is I am getting an error saying "NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance" I believe that I am creating my dictionary wrong or putting the dictionary into the array incorrectly. Could that be why?

Comment: Read the rest of the error message.... what follows *"unrecognized selector sent to instance"*?

Comment: Well, you haven't shown any code related to `ticketNo`, so can't help you there. It's beyond the scope of your original question anyway.

Comment: oh sorry I didnt meant to put ticketNo in there it was supposed to be "length" Ill edit the error

Comment: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281c00f80' libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" I dont know if that will make a difference?

Comment: I believe its crashing because im passing an array to a label for the table instead of just a string, so would you know how to pass that array to the cell.label so it can actually read it?

Comment: I figured it out, thankyou for all your help though